# Only one package appearing in NuGet Package Manager Browse tab

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-2017

The company I work at keeps all of its NuGet packages in a shared network folder which is referenced in the NuGet Settings, while all of the NuGet packages are visible in the folder, only one would appear in NuGet Package Manager under the browse tab. I am not using a filter or search either, so I'm unsure why this is happening. Interestingly, the package which is showing is the most recently updated package available.

I am running Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise in Administrator on Windows 8.1.

Has anyone else had this issue? How would I solve it?

Comment: Are the packages in the shared network folder prerelease maybe?
You might need to check the "prerelease" box in the NuGet Package manager UI.

Answer (score 1):

> Has anyone else had this issue? How would I solve it?

Just as imps comment. You should make sure the checkbox "**Include prerelease**" is checked and the package source "**shared network folder**" is selected:

[image]

If you have already done that, please double check if the package source is correct or you can share us some screenshots of this issue so that we can read this question more intuitive.

Comment: We already fixed it. I'm not sure entirely what was happening but it was something to do with the file directories/structure on the shared network folder where our NuGet packages were being kept. The one which was only showing was using a different file directory structure than all the other ones were. I think because of this, NuGet assumed that they would all be using the same one, resulting in no other packages being found.

Comment: @SamBunting, thanks for your reply and glad to know that you have resolved this issue. You can convert your comment to the answer and mark it, so it could help other community members who get the same issues. Besides, if you don`t mind you can share your the correct structure diagram to us. Thanks.